# Capture Ctrl+C (SIGINT) when terminal is in raw mode?

Tags: terminal, signals, sigint

So, imagine I have raw mode enabled in an application.
The application may or may not take input.

**What would be the best practise to capture Ctrl+C (SIGINT)?** Remember it doesn't *always take* input, so that makes the whole thing a tiny bit harder.

My idea is that I always take input in the background, and use that to see if somebody presses Ctrl+C, and discarding all input unless, well, Ctrl+C, or that I do actually do something with the input.
*Flaws* with this idea is that I believe you can rebind SIGINT to other keys. Also, always taking input might not be the best practise, nor would it be completely painless to implement.

Do I just give up on raw mode completely? Do I only enable it when I need it? (A.K.A. every time I want a single char?)

Comment: That's what **`cbreak`** mode is used for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen for character code 3, which gets sent when you press ctrl-c in raw mode.

Comment: That's what I meant by ```My idea is that I always take input in the background, and use that to see if somebody presses Ctrl+C, and discarding all input unless, well, Ctrl+C, or that I do actually do something with the input.```. Although I ended up solving it by combining it with ```Do I only enable it when I need it? (A.K.A. every time I want a single char?)```